# Gas estimation failed - remix.ethereum.org

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development, remix, tokens

[image]

Why i cant deploy my contract ? it show me every time this. I am sure i do everything right. Before i try force sending but TX failed and i burn some eth...
here is tx

https://etherscan.io/tx/0x487f043da76448fa357a477f195c7306bc310f424937199d3b1f58b64480733d

Comment: Please share the [minimum reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your contract that you’re trying to deploy.

Comment: PUSH1 opcode is failing, please share the code.

Comment: Here is code guys https://codeshare.io/qAnoyz